# Summing variables in a memory block

Tags: pointers

/*I was trying to create a memory dynamically and then sum up the value as which is inputted I would do in an array but I do not understand the cause of Logical error.*/

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

    int numOfElements,*intPtr,sum = 0;
    scanf("%d\n",&numOfElements);
    intPtr = (int *) malloc(numOfElements * sizeof(int));
    int *endOfInt = intPtr +numOfElements-1;
    for(;intPtr<=endOfInt;intPtr++){
        scanf("%d", intPtr);
        sum += *intPtr;
    }
    printf("\n%d\n",sum);
    free(intPtr);


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line `for(;intPtr<=endOfInt;intPtr++){` you are incrementing your pointer variabl intPtr.
On this line `free(intPtr);` you try to free the memory allocated above. 
However, intPtr has not the same value that was returned to you from malloc at this point.

In general, the address passed to free() must be the exact same which was returned from malloc().

Comment: Thanks, I got it I could have put to it's the original address or created another pointer for. the traverse.